# input field to pass the javascript array

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to have a input field where user can input the array and the function which it passes the value treats it as an array?  To be clear, is this possible using javascript and HTML?

```
<input....of some type....>

function (from input as a form of array){

calculation
}
```

I would like to have an input field where I can input something like `[1,2,3,4..]` or `[(1,2),(2,3)...]` and pass that to the function without any further manipulation, hoping that it will treat the array as array not as 'text'. I think I can use `eval` but I don't want to trust the user.

Comment: What would `[(1, 2), (2, 3)]` end up creating exactly?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker:it is something from python I cannot forget.nothing, I know in javascript it creates...just used it for illustration.

Comment: That won't do what you expect it to in JavaScript. You could use `JSON.parse` for the simple array though.

Comment: JSON.parse would help, or if that is not available, either a simple split(",") and a mapping to turn strings into numbers or you need to use a regular expression to get multi-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) will help out here

[Support is IE8+](http://caniuse.com/#feat=json)

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="t1" value="[1,2,3,4,5,6]"/>
<input type="text" id="t2" value="[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]"/>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var a1 = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("t1").value);
var a2 = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("t2").value);
console.log(a1);
console.log(a2);
```

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/NNcg7/

Comment: I think your caps lock is stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array from the text input if the data is entered with a standard delimiter. Meaning, if the user inputs 1,2,3,4 into the text field, you can create an array in Javascript using the split method.

```
var myInputValue = document.getElementById(yourElementId); //value will be "1,2,3,4"
var myArray = myInputValue.split(","); //value will be [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: Problem with split is the indexes are filled with strings and not numbers.